# condition for winning in tic tac toe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tic-tac-toe

Here's my code for tic tac toe game but winning condition isn't working , sometime it shows multiple alert. I used every box as a button.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     var m=1;var butt22;
   $("button").unbind().click(function() {
   var ki=  this.id;
     var mi= ki.split('butt')[1];
     butt_click(mi);
     function butt_click(man){
        if(m==1){
            $("#dee"+man).html("X");
             $("#butt"+man).prop("disabled",true);
              m=0;
              win();
              return false;
          }
          if(m==0){
             $("#dee"+man).html("O");
               $("#butt"+man).prop("disabled",true);
             m=1;
             win();
            return false;
          }
          }
      });
```

function for condition of winning is here. Every time button is clicked and this function is called.

```
  function win(){
   var  str="X";
   var stri="O";
if(($("#dee11").text() && $("#dee12").text() && $("#dee13").text()=== str ) || ( $("#dee11").text() && $("#dee12").text() && $("#dee13").text()=== stri )){
  alert("you win ");}

if(($("#dee22").text() && $("#dee21").text() && $("#dee23").text()=== str ) || ( $("#dee21").text() && $("#dee22").text() && $("#dee23").text()=== stri )){
  alert("you win ");}

  if(($("#dee31").text() && $("#dee32").text() && $("#dee33").text()=== str ) || ( $("#dee31").text() && $("#dee32").text() && $("#dee33").text()=== stri )){
  alert("you win ");}
  if(($("#dee11").text() && $("#dee21").text() && $("#dee31").text()=== str ) || ( $("#dee11").text() && $("#dee21").text() && $("#dee31").text()=== stri )){
  alert("you win ");}
  if(($("#dee12").text() && $("#dee22").text() && $("#dee32").text()=== str ) || ( $("#dee12").text() && $("#dee22").text() && $("#dee32").text()=== stri )){
  alert("you win ");}
  if(($("#dee13").text() && $("#dee23").text() && $("#dee33").text()=== str ) || ( $("#dee13").text() && $("#dee23").text() && $("#dee33").text()=== stri )){
  alert("you win ");}
  if(($("#dee11").text() && $("#dee22").text() && $("#dee33").text()=== str ) || ( $("#dee11").text() && $("#dee22").text() && $("#dee33").text()=== stri )){
  alert("you win ");}
  if(($("#dee13").text() && $("#dee22").text() && $("#dee31").text()=== str ) || ( $("#dee13").text() && $("#dee22").text() && $("#dee31").text()=== stri )){
  alert("you win ");}

}</script>
```

Comment: You can't use `&&` to test if multiple variables are equal to the same thing. Each has to be separate, such as `x === 5 && y === 5 && z === 5`. You can't do `x && y && z === 5`